# How to access partial view model using jquery

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am having one view with partial view containing set of dropdown list. On the click of save button on main view needs to check if atleast one dropdown value is selected or not. I am not able to get the dropdown fields of partial view using jquery. On click of save button jquery call is written. Kindly help

Comment: show ur script at least, we won't know what actually is happening by just reading ur story

Comment: show your View and Partial View Code along with javascript code